# Python dataframe sum rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe with `n` rows, is there a way to set the ith row to be sum of `row[i]` and `row[i-1]` and do this so that the assignment to earlier rows is reflected in the latter rows? I would really like to avoid loops if possible.

Example DF:

```
             SPY   AAPL   GOOG
2011-01-10  0.44  -0.81   1.80
2011-01-11  0.00   0.00   0.00
2011-01-12 -1.11  -2.77  -0.86
2011-01-13 -0.91  -4.02  -0.68
```

Sample pseudo code of summing two rows:

```
DF[2011-01-11] = DF[2011-01-10] + DF[2011-01-11]
DF[2011-01-12] = DF[2011-01-11] + DF[2011-01-12]
```

and so on.

Comment: I think you mean to sum along columns. I suggest you change that (in the title if possible) to make this easier to find for over users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your question, you are looking for a cumulative sum of each columns. you could use the `cumsum()` method

```
DF.cumsum()

               SPY    AAPL   GOOG
2011-01-10  0.4400 -0.8100 1.8000
2011-01-11  0.4400 -0.8100 1.8000
2011-01-12 -0.6700 -3.5800 0.9400
2011-01-13 -1.5800 -7.6000 0.2600
```

Comment: No I did actually mean to say that.

Comment: i. e. row[i]=row[i-1]+row[i] but row[i-1] is not the original row but rather the sum of row[i-1] and row[i-2]

Answer (score 1):

Use `DF.shift()`

```
DF + DF.shift()
```